# No buffer size limit in bufio.NewReader.ReadString()?

Tags: go

I have a socket client that read response like this:

```
message, err := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
```

It works perfectly, but the ReadString method seems to have no limit on the buffer size.

Is it possible to add one? I didn't find much in bufio's document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example,

```
message, err := bufio.NewReaderSize(conn, 1024).ReadString('\n')
```

---

To limit the data read, use an `io.LimitedReader`. For example,

```
rdr := bufio.NewReader(&io.LimitedReader{R: conn, N: 1024})
message, err := rdr.ReadString('\n')
```

Comment: `ReadString` method is higher level function, it doesn't limit buffer size, it copies whole data to new `[]byte`. default buffer size is `4096`. one should use `ReadSlice`method if one doesn't want to copy data.